# Assiging staticmethod to an existing instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods, static-methods

I am working on an rpg and I am looking into a leveling up system. Basically when the player reaches a new level I want to be able to assign new methods to the player instance.

In the simple example below, the class `C` contains a method `a` which I want to add to the instance `aa` of class `A`.

```
from types import MethodType
import inspect

class C(object):

    @staticmethod
    def a(x):
            print 'print {}'.format(x)


class A(object):
    pass

def change_method(instance,method,cls_dest):
    instance.method = MethodType(method, instance, cls_dest)

#creating instance of A 
aa = A()

#extracting method a
method_to_add = inspect.getmembers(C(), predicate=inspect.isfunction)[0][1]

#adding method a to class A
change_method(aa,method_to_add,type(aa))
```

I have tried extracting the method using `inspect` and then adding `a` to `aa`, but I get the following error:

```
aa.a(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-ea48aa2d0995>", line 1, in <module>
    aa.a(3)

AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'a'
```

My idea was to make a class (here `C`) which would contain all the methods I want to override in my instance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to *enable* existing methods, rather than adding new ones? For example, just put `if self.level < some_threshold: raise ValueError("not yet!")` at the start of the methods.

Comment: Also, note that `instance.method` is setting a method *literally called method*. Did you mean `setattr(instance, method.__name__, MethodType(...))`? And why is `'a'`, the name of the method you're trying to add, nowhere to be seen in your source code?

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing it that way. I will give it a think and get back in touch if I encounter problems.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes that's what I want to achieve. A is the staticmethod: def a(x)